# Code to ignore all of document except for list environments and sections

Tags: comments, preview

I am trying to typeset all of the (description) lists in my document without any of the surrounding text or figures (with the exception of desiring some context by way of section headings).

I thought that the `preview` package could help, and have a MWE working, but it typesets everything on individual pages.  I can't see an option that would change this behavior.

Is there a way to do this type of parsing, but have all the content appear with pagination dictated by the traditional TeX methods?

The `xcomment` package (http://ctan.org/pkg/xcomment) almost does this, but doesn't appear to support allowing section headings through.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}


%% Use below code to get just an outline and description lists
\usepackage[active,delayed,tightpage,pdftex]{preview}
\PreviewMacro[*[!]{\section} % Include Section headings
\PreviewMacro[*[!]{\subsection} % Include Subsection headings
\PreviewEnvironment{description} % Include description environments
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{2ex} % Give a little bit of a border
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\section{Short lists}
\blinditemize
\blindtext
\blinddescription
\blindtext
\section{Long lists}
\begin{description}
\item[First] \blindtext
\item[Second] \blindtext
\end{description}
\blindenumerate

\end{document}
```

This gives separate pages...:

[image: pages]

**Side question:**

When I remove the `tightpages` option, the lists are not all contained in the page.  This is seen most obviously with the long lists, shown below.  Is this normal?  How is it fixed?

[image: longlists]