# Preview package cutting off top of content

Tags: preview

When the `preview` package is loaded, the `tikzpicture/figure` environment that I am trying to isolate becomes set too high, resulting in the top of the image being cut off.  (This is similar behavior to the "Side Question" part of [Code to ignore all of document except for list environments and sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174032), so I don't believe it to be directly related to the `tikzpicture` or `figure` environments, nor the `floats` option.)

However, when I load the `preview` package with the `tightpage` option, everything comes out fine (so long as I have made the `papersize` big enough using `geometry` beforehand,  as has been mentioned in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62325/)).  I'd like to be able to have all figures on a common page size, however, so `tightpage` isn't really what I'm after in this case.

**What causes `preview` to incorrectly place the content and effectively trim off the top?**

---

`preview` version 11.87, dated 2010/02/14

---

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry} % Make paper super big, fixes tightpage option cutting off right of image

% This works okay now with tightpage option set once papersize is made bigger
%\usepackage[active,floats,delayed,tightpage,pdftex]{preview} 

% Without tightpage, this form still cuts off the *top* of the image
\usepackage[active,floats,delayed,pdftex]{preview} 

% Define a few styles for use in making the figures
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows,positioning}

\tikzstyle{block}=[
    draw, fill=blue!80!black!20,
    anchor=north,
    text width=13.0em, text centered,
    minimum height=1.5em,drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{flowline}=[
    draw, very thick,
    color=black, -latex,
    font=\tt]

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
% Nodes
\path             node  (p1)    [block] {Flowchart Block Text};
\path (p1.south)+(0,-1.5) node  (p2)    [block] {Flowchart Block Text};
\path (p2.south)+(0,-1.5) node  (p3)    [block] {Flowchart Block Text};
\path (p3.south)+(0,-1.5) node  (p4)    [block] {Flowchart Block Text};

% Connectors
\path   [flowline]  (p1.south) -- node [right,align=left] {Flow Label} (p2);
\path   [flowline]  (p2.south) -- node [right] {Flow Label} (p3);
\path   [flowline]  (p3.south) -- node [right] {Flow Label} (p4);

% Alternate Start
\node (p1alt) [block,left=of p1,text width=10em] {Flowchart Block Text};
\path   [flowline, dashed]  (p1alt.south) |- node {} (p2.west);

% Optional Output
\node (next) [block,right=of p4,text width=10em] {Flowchart Block Text};
\path   [flowline, dashed]  (p4.east) -- node {} (next.west);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\label{workflow}%
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Weird. It almost looks as if it is placing the graphic on the baseline (of what would be the first line of text).

Comment: I don't know why this happens, but the option `baseline=0` to `tikzpicture` seems to fix the problem.

Comment: @giordano : I confirm.

Comment: @doed  This question is about the LaTeX `preview` package, not about the AUCTeX preview feature (based on the LaTeX `preview` package and created by the same author).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why this happens, but the option `baseline=0` to `tikzpicture` seems to do the trick:

**Without `baseline=0` option:**

> [image: Without <code>baseline=0</code> option]

**With `baseline=0` option:**

> [image: With <code>baseline=0</code> option]

Comment: This provides a workaround, but it still doesn't answer the original question: why is this behavior seen? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a bug?

Comment: @cslstr  As I already said: I don't have a clue.  If you want to report a bug for the `preview` package, please write an email to `bug-auctex@gnu.org`.

Comment: @giordano interesting. I played with it a bit, and I could be wrong whether it's a bug with that package, but I get the same output as your answer, as long as the `figure` environment is not in the document.

Comment: @giordano I've awarded you the full bounty (why not?) but have not accepted you answer at this point as I feel like the underlying question still does not have a complete answer.